# What does a cyclic difference matrix mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am reading "Introduction to Linear Algebra". And there is an example about "Cyclic difference matrix". I will write the question

$$ Cx = b \\
\begin{bmatrix}
0  & 1 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 1\\
0  & -1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\ x_3\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_2 - 0\\x_3 - x_1\\ 0-x_2\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1\\b_2\\ b_3\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

> Show that $Cx = b$ can only be solved when $b_1 + b_3 = 0$. That is a plane of vectors $b$ in three-dimensional space. Each column of $C$ is in the plane, the matrix has no inverse. So this plane contains all the cobinations of those columns (which are all the vectors $Cx$).

There is a solution provided but I don't quite understand it. Can someone explain it in there own words so I can look at it from a different point of view. I can see that $b_1$ and $b_2$, why does that imply that it can only be solved if $b_1$ and $b_2$ equal to zero and non-invert-able. isn't that just a consequence of them being those specific value. I can see that it is non-invertible because column 1 is a multiple of column 3.

Answer (score 1):

From $\begin{bmatrix}
0  & 1 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 1\\
0  & -1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\ x_3\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_2 - 0\\x_3 - x_1\\ 0-x_2\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1\\b_2\\ b_3\\
\end{bmatrix}$

we get $x_2=b_1$ (first row) and $-x_2=b_3$ (third row).

Hence $b_3=-x_2=-b_1$.